# Is instantiating an object from an external class thread safe so long as it's done locally?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

So I'm learning about concurrency, thread-safety and other associated topics through a program that I'm attempting to adapt to a multi-threaded model.

Here is some an illustration of what I'm doing.

```
public class readerThread implements Runnable {

    private static BlockQueue<String> iqueue
    private static BlockingQueue<Object> oqueue
    private static ThreadLocal<java.util.ArrayList<File>> fileList = new ThreadLocal<java.util.ArrayList<File>>();  
    private static int FILE_BATCH_SIZE = 50;

    public void run() {
    fileList.set(new ArrayList<File>());
    ThreadLocal<Integer> i = new ThreadLocal<Integer>();    
    i.set(1);

        for (int y = i.get(); i<1000000; i.set(y++)) {

            try {

                File datafile = new File(iqueue.poll(86400, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {           
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (datafile == null || datafile == POISION) {
                break;
            }

            fileList.get().add(datafile);
            ...
            ...

            if (fileList.get().size() == FILE_BATCH_SIZE || (iqueue.peek() == null) || (iqueue.peek() == POISON) ) {
                parseAndWrite();
                fileList.get().clear();         

            }






        }

    }



    public void parseAndWrite() {

        for (File f : fileList.get()) {
            Long fileTs = f.lastModified()
            String fileName = String.valueOf(f);

            Filelog filelog = new Filelog()
            Asset asset = new Asset()

            Parser parser = new Parser(f);
            // Parser returns an Asset
            asset = parser.parse()
            String assetTag = asset.getAssetTag();      


            filelog.setTimeStamp(fileTs);
            filelog.setFileName(fileName);
            filelog.setAssetTag(assetTag);
            filelog.setProcessed(false);

            HibernateWrapper.commit(filelog);

            oqueue.put(asset);


            .....
            .....


        }

    }



}
```

Please ignore any obvious errors in the example as it was hastily put together. 
Effectively several readerThreads take files from an blockingqueue, extract data as an object and write the object to a database using Hibernate. Let's assume for a moment that the HibernateWrapper is 100% thread safe; since the data in the asset object is associated with files taken from the queue and since each thread is working on a different file, is it thread-safe? 
Forgive me if my terminology is off. Basically I believe some of my prior code was racey as I observed some examples where rows of data written were associated with wrong objects (e.g file foo has bar's assettag).

Comment: 'Is instantiating an object ... thread safe' yes. 'From an external class': irrelevant. 'So long as it's done locally': meaningless. Your code doesn't compile. Code that relies on the success of code in a prior `try` block should have been inside that `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety is an issue when there's shared state between threads. If your code is such that each thread has its own set of variables, then the code is thread-safe. That is more difficult than it sounds because of the possible shared state for other functions or third party libraries you call, because they may introduce shared state among threads.

Your use of `fileList` as a thread-local is correct, but it looks like it is unnecessary because you can pass it to the `parseAndWrite` method as an argument.

Your use of thread-local `i` is unnecessary, because it is a stack variable, and every thread will have its own copy.